# How to find out root cause analysis using JMeter integration with Prometheus and Grafana?

Tags: performance, jmeter, prometheus, performance-testing, monitoring

Requirements is to find out root cause analysis using Prometheus and Grafana and also need to know which method is taking more time, CPU and Memory Utilisation also?

Can anyone pls help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Integrate [Prometheus client library](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) into your app
2. Configure Grafana dashboard to visualize the metrics you want to monitor from your app
3. Additionally you can integrate JMeter with [Prometheus Listener for JMeter](https://github.com/johrstrom/jmeter-prometheus-plugin#prometheus-listener-for-jmeter) plugin (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager))
4. Come up with a test plan which simulates a real life usage of your application
5. Run a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) (start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable threshold or errors start occurring)
6. Inspect Grafana dashboard to see what is the reason of the application being slow, i.e. trace down the "slow" request to the underlying function. Additionally you can use a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) which can provide a better picture